# Remover espaço entre item de lista html

Tags: html, css

Tenho a seguinte lista:

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Como faço para colar os itens da lista sem ter que colocar uma margem com valor negativo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Este espaçamento ocorre porque os elementos com `inline-block` faz com que espaçamentos de quebra de linhas ou espaços normais afetem a renderização, já que este é o efeito esperado da propriedades que usam `inline`  (como `inline-block` e `inline-table`)

Para corrigir você pode usar `float:;` e `clear` com um *"pseudo elemento"* (`::after`):

```css
.itens {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.itens > li {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
}

.itens::after {
  clear:both;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="itens">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Ou definir a `font-size` como `0` no `ul`:

```css
.itens {
  font-size: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.itens > li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
  font-size: 11pt;
}
```

```html
<ul class="itens">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Para ver como é as quebras de linha que afetam remova qualquer espaço entre os LIs:

```css
.itens {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.itens > li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
  font-size: 11pt;
}
```

```html
<ul class="itens">
  <li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Muito boa sua resposta amigo, resolveu meu problema, obrigado.

Comment: @LaércioLopes por favor marque como correta a resposta que mais lhe agradou, como aceitar: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/3635

Comment: Macado, obrigado não tinha feito isso antes...

Answer (score 4):

Uma outra sugestão é usar comentários no HTML entre os `LI's` para ficar bem identado.

```css
.itens {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.itens > li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
  font-size: 11pt;
}
```

```html
<ul class="itens">
     <li>Item 1</li><!--
  --><li>Item 2</li><!--
  --><li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica amigo, isso ajuda a deixar o código legível.

Answer (score -3):

```
<head>
 <style>
    .itens {
        list-style: none;
        margin-left:-5%;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<ul class="itens">
 <li>Item 1</li>
 <li>Item 2</li>
 <li>Item 3</li>
 <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>

</body>
```