# Como fazer uma sequências de caixas com a borda em formato triangular à direita, em cima da outra, caixa com CSS?

Tags: css, css3

Não soube um título melhor para descrever minha necessidade, mas na verdade, eu gostaria de conseguir fazer uma sequência de caixas cuja borda da direita estivesse num formato triangular, sobreposta à caixa subsequente.

Assim:

[image: Caixas sobrepondo a outra no formato de setas/triangulo]

A minha ideia é colocar um texto centralizado em cada um dos itens indicados por cores diferentes acima, numa espécie de régua para status.

Qual seria a forma mais eficiente de fazer isso com CSS?

Comment: Vou fazer no Codepen de um jeito que eu faria.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Um dos jeitos tradicionais é usar o "border triangle":

```css
.breadcrumb {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  line-height:30px;                /* altura final da linha */
  text-align:center;
  padding-right:20px;
  padding-left:35px;               /* 1/2 da altura da linha a mais */
                                   /* que o right para compensar o bico */
  color:#fff;
}
.breadcrumb:after {
  content:"";display:block;position:absolute;
  box-sizing:border-box;           /* para respeitar medida interna */
  top:0;bottom:0;left:100%;
  border:solid 15px transparent;   /* metade da altura da linha */
  z-index:1;
}

.blue {background:blue}  .blue:after {border-left-color:blue}
.gold {background:gold}  .gold:after {border-left-color:gold}
.green{background:green} .green:after{border-left-color:green}
.red  {background:red}   .red:after  {border-left-color:red}
```

```html
   <span class="breadcrumb blue">UM</span><!--
--><span class="breadcrumb gold">DOIS</span><!--
--><span class="breadcrumb green">TRÊS</span><!--
--><span class="breadcrumb red">QUATRO</span>
```

Esta é apenas uma demonstração da técnica, o importante a se observar é o uso do pseudoelemento, e do border.

No caso, usei `<span>` para simplificar (por isso os comments para matar quebra de linha), você tem que escolher o display mais adequado para o seu caso. Sobre o espaçamento dos elementos, tem esse post aqui:

> [Remover espaço entre item de lista html](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172075/70)

Comment: Ao invés de colocar comentários HTML para tirar o espaço entre os elementos, dá pra se criar um elemento que envolve esses 4 elementos e colocar a propriedade `font-size: 0`. Mas dentro dos elementos tem que colocar um `font-size` para que as palavras apareçam.

Comment: @DiegoSouza eu acho o font size mais gambi do que os comments, mas grato pela dica de qq forma. É que o foco aqui era o bico, na verdade eu acho que nem seria o caso de usar span. Procurei usar o minimo de elementos possível para mostrar que a técnica independe de um container externo. Eu não gosto de `font:0` pq apesar dele esconder o espaço, o nó do elemento fica no DOM, e o comment não.

Comment: Sim, verdade. Por isso que disse para se atentar em colocar o `font-size` nos elementos descendentes.

Comment: Eu mesmo postei uma resposta com essa alternativa de comentários. kkkkkk que irônico.

Comment: @DiegoSouza eu lembrava desse post, linkei pela referência e tb para fazer graça com o lance do seu HTML comment :D Saiu bastante conversa sobre essas técnicas na época, por isso eu sabia que tinha post

Comment: Eu acho legal essas coisas de CSS, desafios. O PT StackOverflow poderia criar uma área de desafios. Onde um usuário poderia criar uma competição para realizar determinada situação no CSS. Fazer uma carta de baralho, por exemplo. O mais legal, o vencedor, ganharia 100 pontos. Estou viajando aqui... mas engajaria a comunidade e serviria de aprendizado para várias técnicas de CSS, HTML

Comment: Pra ser honesto, eu usaria `display: inline-flex` ou `display: flex` pra organizar os itens aí dentro.

Comment: Quando eu voltar do mato  vou fazer um resposta com linear gradiente :D

Comment: @WallaceMaxters por isso coloquei lá "você tem que escolher o display mais adequado para o seu caso." :P - eu procurei fazer o exemplo pra ficar compatível com bastante coisa, mas com flex vai funcionar numa boa.

Answer (score 5):

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

ul.menu {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 0;
}
ul.menu li {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: #fff 1px 1px 5px;
  position: relative;
}
ul.menu li:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  right: -12px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 24px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: auto;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: 1;
}
ul.menu li:first-child {
  background-color: #b4be35;
}
ul.menu li:first-child:after {
  background-color: #b4be35;
}
ul.menu li:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #ff00ff;
}
ul.menu li:nth-child(2):after {
  background-color: #ff00ff;
}
ul.menu li:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
ul.menu li:nth-child(3):after {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
ul.menu li:last-child {
  background-color: #00ffff;
}
ul.menu li:last-child:after {
  background-color: #00ffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>Link---1</li>
    <li>Link---2</li>
    <li>Link---3</li>
    <li>Link---4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: +1, boa tambem, rotacionar um quadrado é bem legal. Vale dizer que a relação entre a altura dos dois elementos é de 1,4142 (raiz de 2, é a diagonal do quadrado) para que fiquem iguais, para quem for calcular para outras medidas.

Comment: Eu fiz com SCSS. No Codepen fica mais elegante.

Comment: +1, foi ninja dus CSS